# X-Path to a library search engine

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am writing a short scrapper using Google Spreadsheets using Xpatch and IMPORTXML

on that page, I am trying to get in B3 and following all the titles of articles (class 'library-document-summary') and in C3 and follow all the URLS of said articles

however, I am getting nowhere as the returns of my XPATH are always empty. Could someone with knowledge in this area help?

```
B2= https://resources.norrag.org/categories/591,595

=IMPORTXML(B2,"//div//a[@class='library-document-summary']/text()")
```

Comment: What result do you expect to get from the `=IMPORTXML(...)` function?

Comment: I would like to get the title of each articles and their links in the example URL I have it should be: title: Towards Better Skills Development in the Vietnam 2018 General Education Curriculum (in one column) and URL in another column. Thanks for looking at the question!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `IMPORTXML` function supports XPaths that select text nodes. But I think if your XPath selects the `a` elements themselves, then their text content will be imported. e.g.

```xml
//div[@id='article_search_results']//a
```

... and for the links:

```
//div[@id='article_search_results']//a/@href
```

Comment: hum for both I still receive a message that the imported content is empty... also the first a element isn't the title below 'article_search_results, but the article image/then the overline, then the title. how to target this and that Google spreadsheet behaves:-)

Comment: is it possible that because that page https://resources.norrag.org/categories/591,595 is basically a search engine, that it's empty? unless it's actually loaded in a browser?

Comment: @PaulGerhard I believe you are correct. The hyperlinks are inserted into the page by JavaScript after the page has loaded, and I'd assume that Google Sheets is not running that JavaScript but only reading the HTML of the page. It might be necessary to use software such as Selenium WebDriver to automate a browser to retrieve these results?

Comment: Dear Conal, thanks that’s what I suspected what a bummer. Do you think there is a web app that can also do this, and provide a link that can be read by Google sheets? Web driver seem like it needs to run in a server etc… and I don’t have that set up…